# How can I copy an IList to an IList of the same type?

Tags: c#, list

In C#, if I have an `IList`, and I do not know the type of the objects in the `IList`, how can I create a copy of the `IList`?

Here is the situation:

I have a CollectionEditor that can modify items in an `IList`. If the cancel button is pressed, I need to restore the `IList` before the items were changed.

Comment: Hint: Look at the documentation for IList<T>: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: You need to serialize the list, and then deserialized when needed.

Comment: You can use the CopyTo method, you can make use of Generics.

Comment: You can clone the elements when they are implementing Iclonable. If you want to restore the previous state then create a new list and clone every item of the source list and put them into the new list.

Comment: @Bon `CopyTo` only applies when copying to an *array*.

Comment: @Sebastian it is ambiguous whether `ICloneable` is deep vs shallow (hence we must default to "undefined") - a sad design oversight, but one that makes it largely useless.

Answer (score 6):

There are two different problems here. Copying a list to another list is relatively easy - if you don't need the second list to be the exact same type of concrete list you could use `ToList()`, otherwise you could just `Add` in a loop. However, that **won't solve your problem** unless the `T` here is something immutable. It would be fine for `string`, `int` etc, but copying the references to a complex type won't allow you to restore the list, as individual *items* could have been edited in the UI. To solve *that* problem you need a "deep copy" (or there are some other strategies, but that is the simplest). And as has been noted: one way to do a deep copy is: serialization. By taking a snapshot of the data in XML, json, or some other serialization format, "restore" can be implemented via "deserialize".

Of course, if your `T` has a deep-clone method built in, you might be able to use that instead of serialization. It is ambiguous whether `ICloneable` is deep vs shallow, so I don't think it is sufficient to insist `where T : ICloneable`.

Answer (score 3):

ToList creates a copy:

```
IList x = y.ToList();
```

Comment: it does not copy. references of elements would be same. you just get a new list but same elements.

Comment: That creates a shallow copy, which may or may not be sufficient in this case.